# convert irregular date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date-conversion

I am working with a mysql database that somebody else created. I have a table with two different date fields one is called eventDate and is in the format YYYY-MM-DD and the other is called creationDate and is in the format M/D/YYYY H:MM:SS AM/PM

What I want to do is query the table and return results where the eventDate is the same as the creationDate but how do I convert the creationDate into YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: You can use the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format or just change schema of your database.

Comment: "the other is called creationDate and is in the format M/D/YYYY H:MM:SS AM/PM" that sounds strange. MySQL has timestamp and datetime data types, but by default the format is always YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Please post a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table-name>` so we can see what the defined data types are in that table.

Comment: Like I said, I inherited the table from someone else. It looks like the creationDate is a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and a [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) matching the one used by your `creationDate` strings:

```
SELECT
…
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(creationDate, '%c/%e/%Y %r')) = STR_TO_DATE(eventDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Perhaps MySQL would be able to convert `YYYY-MM-DD` strings to dates implicitly, so the second `STR_TO_DATE()` call might be unnecessary.